# How to rectify this error in my scenario _NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

[image: This is my demo project screen shot.]

In this screen shot i have two dropdowns issues and projects.If i scroll issues drop down it shows the error _NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'.Eventhough i fetch values dynamically.

My json response like this  for projects dropdown:

```
 {
     "projects": [
      {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Andriod APP",
      "identifier": "andriod-app",
      "description": "",
      "status": 1,
      "is_public": true,
      "created_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z",
      "updated_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z"
       },
       ],
      "total_count": 8,
      "offset": 0,
      "limit": 25
      }

my json response like this for issues drpdown
    {
  "issues": [
    {
      "id": 22,
      "project": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Vitals"
      },
      "tracker": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Support"
      },
      "status": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "New"
      },
      "priority": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Normal"
      },
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Redmine Admin"
      },
      "subject": "Lead page creation",
      "description": "",
      "start_date": "2015-06-25",
      "done_ratio": 0,
      "created_on": "2015-06-25T10:22:22Z",
      "updated_on": "2015-06-25T10:22:22Z"
    },
    ],
  "total_count": 17,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 25
}
```

My piece of code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnoutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray * data;
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnoutlet1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray * data1;
- (IBAction)btnAction1:(id)sender;
@end

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// to fetch and parse json response of projects dropdown
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURLWithString:@"http:xxx/projects.json"]];
NSError * error = nil;
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSData * jsonSource = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
returningResponse:&response error:&error];
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
if ([jsonObjects objectForKey:@"projects"] != [NSNull null]) {
self.data = [jsonObjects  objectForKey:@"projects"];
NSLog(@" %@",self.data);
}
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.tableFooterView =[UIView  new];
//  to fetch and parse the json response of issues dropdown
NSURLRequest * urlRequest1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:       [NSURLURLWithString:@"http:xxx/redmine/issues.json"]];
NSError * error1 = nil;
NSURLResponse * response1 = nil;
NSData * jsonSource1 = [NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest1returningResponse:&response1error:&error1];
id jsonObjects1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource1  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
if ([jsonObjects1 objectForKey:@"issues"] != [NSNull null]) {
self.data1 = [jsonObjects1 objectForKey:@"issues"];
NSLog(@" %@",self.data1);
}
self.tableView1.delegate = self;
self.tableView1.dataSource = self;
self.tableView1.tableFooterView =[UIView  new];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(tableView == self.tableView)
{
return [self.data count];
}
if(tableView == self.tableView1)
{
return [self.data1 count];
}
return 0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
NSDictionary * tmpdict = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict);
NSDictionary * tmpdict2 = [self.data1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict2);
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
if(tableView == self.tableView){
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.textLabel.text = [tmpdict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@ " %@",cell.textLabel.text);
}
else if(tableView == self.tableView1) {
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.textLabel.text = [tmpdict2 objectForKey:@"subject"];
NSLog(@ " %@",cell.textLabel.text);
}
// cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView==self.tableView) {
UITableViewCell * Cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.btnoutlet setTitle:Cell.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.tableView.hidden = YES;
}
if (tableView==self.tableView1) {
UITableViewCell * Cell = [self.tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.btnoutlet1 setTitle:Cell.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.tableView1.hidden = YES;
}
}
```

where might be the error? In this code or any modification needed.Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: Do this: `NSDictionary * tmpdict = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict);
NSDictionary * tmpdict2 = [self.data1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict2);` only in the test and in the correct one of if (tableView == self.tableView or self.tableView1).

Comment: thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put:

```
NSDictionary * tmpdict = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict);
NSDictionary * tmpdict2 = [self.data1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict2);
```

inside appropriate `if` conditions. In current scenario if the `self.data` and `self.data1` counts comes as different then it will crash.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   }

   if(tableView == self.tableView)
   {
      NSDictionary * tmpdict = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict);
      cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
      cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
      cell.textLabel.text = [tmpdict objectForKey:@"name"];
      NSLog(@ " %@",cell.textLabel.text);
   }
   else if(tableView == self.tableView1)
   {
      NSDictionary * tmpdict2 = [self.data1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict2);
      cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
      cell.textLabel.text = [tmpdict2 objectForKey:@"subject"];
      NSLog(@ " %@",cell.textLabel.text);
   }
   // cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter ....i wish to add the image only....if you get 10 reputations then only....it shows alert thst's why i post image like this....

Comment: yeah bro is it possible to combine the subject and id in the single text label . is it possible.?

Comment: @catherine007: You can, you can use the stringWithFormat: method of nsstring to achieve that